# Split binary string such that every substring has the same number of 1's and 0's

Tags: algorithm, binary, substring, combinations, permutation

I was trying to split a binary string such that each substring has the same number of 1's and 0's. By this I mean, given a string like 0010110010, it can be split into 00101 10010 with both substrings having 2 ones and 3 zeros. Could anyone point me to something similar. Sorry, I don't have any code to share.

Comment: The problem seems under-specified.  A string like (01)^n can be split in a number of ways that's exponential in n.  Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @Gene: Unless I'm missing something, (01)ⁿ can only be split in O(n) ways: one way for each of *n*'s divisors. (For example, the divisors of 6 are 1, 2, 3, and 6, so 010101010101 can be split into one substring (010101010101), two substrings (010101 and 010101), three substrings (0101, 0101, and 0101), or four substrings (01, 01, 01, 01, 01, and 01).) But either way, you're right, there's obviously more than one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Say a given string can be split into **n** substrings that meet the condition, each of which has **a** 0's and **b** 1's. Guess what? All the substrings must have the same length (== **a + b**)! Therefore the search space is very limited:

1. You try to divide the length of the original string by 2,3,4...`(int)string.length()/2`. Only divisors without a remainder could be a valid one. For example, you have string 010010010, you *can't* divide it into 2 substrings and let both substrings have the equal number of 0's and 1's because 9/2=4 R 1.
2. You just try divisors one by one. Say dividing the original string into **n** two-character long substrings then I can check if substrings[0], substring[1]...have the same number of 0's and 1's...

If you only need one solution, the time complexity should be no more than `o(n^2)`

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Yes, I know all the substrings have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

- *N* substrings of the number of ones *K1* and zeros *K0*, means substrings of the same length.
- The entire string must be of length *N*(K1+K0)*.
- Also the entire string must have *N*K1* ones and *N*K0* zeros.
- So you can count all ones, *NK1*, derive the zeroes count *NK0*, and N is a factor of the *gcd(NK1, NK0)*. *(Greatest Common Divisor is a simple algorithm.)*
- There is always a solution: the repetition of 1 substring.

Of course we do not solve tasks here.